# API to access GSM signal on computer

Tags: gsm

Hope this is the right place to ask - assuming so as it is related to programming.

I am looking for some hardware (say a dongle) that would open up an API for my computer to a SIM card.  Does that exist anywhere?

The idea would be that I can then use my existing SIM card on its existing network/contract and with a bit of code,  send/receive calls and texts.  I figured that if a phone can be programmed to do it why can't a computer?  I just need the hardware.

Any suggestions if this kind of thing is possible?  Even by maybe integrating a phone?

Comment: You could use any device, like mobile phone, that is exposed as a modem and use AT commands to communicate with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AT commands with any modem or phone, whose driver exposes a modem port when you connect it to a computer.  Plug in the phone or modem, and go to Windows Device Manager, and look under "Modems" and see what you've got.  From "properties" of the Modem, you can see which COM port it is on.

AT commands are an older method of communicating with a modem.  There is a standard set of commands for GSM/GPRS/3G/4G devices available from [3GPP.org, here.](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/27007.htm)  Manufacturers add their own proprietary commands for more obscure functions.  Many but not all of these are in the public domain.

Some newer plug-in modems may appear as a network adapter (you can see this in Windows), due to their drivers.  In this case, you can use the following interfaces:

on Vista: NDIS, proprietary interfaces
on Windows 7 and 8.x Desktop apps: [Windows Mobile Broadband API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
on Windows 8.x, in the Metro/app area: [Windows.Networking and MobileBroadband APIs.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Mobile-Broadband-API-Sample-7debc1ff)
on Windows 10, UWP, there are UWP APIs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/).  But they do not give as much functionality as the Desktop APIs.

On Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, if the appropriate drives are present it is possible to use the new MBIM interface via the desktop Mobile Broadband DeviceServices API.  [Mobile Broadband Interface Model spec available here.](http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs#approved)

On Linux, use AT commands via the serial port.

I'm a bit puzzled by your requirement to make (voice?) calls via a phone connected to a computer.  Do you mean Skype?  In this case, of course, you wouldn't need any interface for making calls, you would just open an IP connection over a data session - which can be done via any of the above interfaces.

(added this comment as an answer, as there was more information)

Comment: Cheers for the informative answer.  Quick question - is it easy to interface with the AT commands with languages like Java/Python?

Comment: Yes.  Enter [java][at-command] or [python][at-command] in the StackOverflow search box, to get all the questions with both tags, and there's a lot of information there.

Answer (score 0):

I use this GSM device: http://www.mikroe.com/click/gsm2/ connected to a basic UART like: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/718?gclid=CIj1xOzbur4CFUVbfgodCpQASQ

Then use AT COMMANDS.

I also use a piece of software called QNavigator to inspect the modem/gsm: http://www.soselectronic.com/?str=1329